# Nginx - Customizing 404 page

Tags: php, nginx, http-status-code-404

Nginx+PHP (on fastCGI) works great for me. When I enter a path to a PHP file which doesn't exist, instead of getting the default 404 error page (which comes for any invalid .html file), I simply get a "No input file specified.".

How can I customize this 404 error page?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You use the error_page property in the nginx [config](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page).

For example, if you intend to set the 404 error page to `/404.html`, use

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
```

Setting the 500 error page to `/500.html` is just as easy as:

```
error_page 500 /500.html;
```

Comment: Although the link is OK and the answer minimally works without the link, it could benefit from additional elaboration.

Comment: @Paul I 100% agree with you on this, therefore I added some code examples to this answer ;-)

Answer (score 123):

You can setup a custom error page for every location block in your nginx.conf, or a global error page for the site as a whole.

To redirect to a simple 404 not found page for a specific location:

```
location /my_blog {
    error_page    404 /blog_article_not_found.html;
}
```

A site wide 404 page:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    error_page  404  /website_page_not_found.html;
    ...
```

You can append standard error codes together to have a single page for several types of errors:

```
location /my_blog {
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /server_error.html
}
```

To redirect to a totally different server, assuming you had an upstream server named server2 defined in your http section:

```
upstream server2 {
    server 10.0.0.1:80;
}
server {
    location /my_blog {
        error_page    404 @try_server2;
    }
    location @try_server2 {
        proxy_pass http://server2;
    }
```

The [manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) can give you more details, or you can search google for the terms nginx.conf and error_page for real life examples on the web.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to use a error wildcard? Something like `error_page 50* = /error_50x.html;`?

Comment: Wildcards are not allowed - the wiki page for this server command is here http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#error_page - also they aren't necessary since the error codes are defined by the HTTP protocol which doesn't change very often. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes for the complete list and I suppose add whatever numbers you like if you think there will be future codes needed.

Comment: Thanks. Currently I have 3 rules: `/403.html`, `/404.html` and `/5xx.html`, they all share the same `root` but somehow if I specify the location `~ /(?:40[34]|5xx)[.]html$` it will render the default nginx error pages, however, if I use a non-regex location it works. Do you have any idea why that happens?

Comment: That's a separate issue too big to get into in these comments.  I would make it a new question or just add the location entries.  Link to the question if you make one and I will take a look.

Answer (score 41):

Be careful with the syntax! Great Turtle used them interchangeably, but:

`error_page    404 = /404.html;`

Will return the 404.html page with a status code of 200 (because = has relayed that to this page)

`error_page    404 /404.html;`

Will return the 404.html page with a (the original) 404 error code.

https://serverfault.com/questions/295789/nginx-return-correct-headers-with-custom-error-documents

Comment: This is an important detail!

Comment: And 2 years later I've corrected my code.  Thanks dhr_p.  :)

Answer (score 30):

The "error_page" parameter makes a redirect, converting the request method to "GET", it is not a custom response page.

The easiest solution is

```
     server{
         root /var/www/html;
         location ~ \.php {
            if (!-f $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name){
                return 404;
            }
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi_params.default;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
```

By the way, if you want Nginx to process 404 status returned by PHP scripts, you need to add

`[fastcgi_intercept_errors][1] on;`

E.g.

```
     location ~ \.php {
            #...
            error_page  404   404.html;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
         }
```

Comment: thank you so much for posting this @Grigori, I used your code above to fix my nginx problem too

Comment: Perfect, `fastcgi_intercept_errors on` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid because it is a redirect with "request method changed to “GET”", not a custom response, and the request body is lost.

Comment: thanks, i placed the error page destination outside of my location block. 
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on     helped me solved my custom 404 page problem for my laravel forge server.

Answer (score 18):

These answers are no longer recommended since `try_files` works faster than `if` in this context.  Simply add `try_files` in your php location block to test if the file exists, otherwise return a 404.

```
location ~ \.php {
    try_files $uri =404;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This helped me immensely. I haven't found any suggestions for using this on the internet. Had no idea you could use conditionals in try_files.