# django on nginx & apache : where to handle 404 & 500 error?

Tags: django, apache, nginx, http-status-code-404

I know there is 404 error handling in django.
But is it better to just put that config in nginx ?

This ST thread has the solution for putting it.  -
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024199/nginx-customizing-404-page`

Is that how everyone handles it when using nginx ?
I have created my own 404.html & 500.html in the sites theme, want to display them.

Comment: Especially for 404 pages it makes more sense to me to display it using django, since i find it useful to eg. have a navigation on it, that is generated using functionality offered by django (eg. template tags).

Comment: My thought was of not adding any logic in django. If a 404 occurs, the webserver should detect it and display my static page. Same for 500.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't mentioned any reasons why you would want to put these pages in the Nginx server.  I would recommend keeping it with the rest of your site, that is, on the Django server.  Moving part of your site to the Nginx server is a good idea to solve scalability problem, but complicates your deploy.  I certainly hope you aren't seeing a significant fraction of your site's traffic going to your error pages!

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, also folks on #django helped me understand that I can customize it so well. I'll put how I implemented it below. But will select this as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't know how to configure 404 & 500 errors in django.
Thanks to "namnatulco" who helped me.

Here are the steps:

1. Create 2 pages `404.html` & `500.html`
2. Place them in your modules template folder
3. In your modules `urls.conf`, enter these two lines:

   ```
   handler404 = "myproject.mymodule.views.redirect_page_not_found"   
   handler500 = "myproject.mymodule.views.redirect_500_error"
   ```
4. In your view, define the functions

   ```
   def redirect_page_not_found(request):
     return render_to_response('logreg/404.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request));     
   def redirect_500_error(request):
     return render_to_response('logreg/500.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request));
   ```
5. Test it by giving some incorrect URL e.g. - `www.mydomain.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`
6. To test 500 error, inside your view, in your `render_to_response`, give an incorrect URL.

That's it. You should be set.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using an in-Django 404/500 handler. You can deliver meaningful alternate nav suggestions in a page style that is consistent with the rest of your site.

Make sure you do *not* return a page *talking* about the error but sporting a 200 return status -- human will understand it's an error, but programmatic access will not. I'm avoiding saying "search engines" here, but the truth is that they will probably represent 98%+ of your non-human visitors. See [HttpResponse subclasses](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses) for details.