# How do I add a 404 page to a brunch.io project?

Tags: brunch

I have a default brunch project, how do I add a 404 page to it?

I tried putting a 404.jade file in the same folder as index.jade but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your framework. There are programmatic solutions for Backbone, React, Ember, Angular. If you're just using brunch as a static site generator, there is no simple way to add 404 page. You'll need to adjust your web server like nginx or apache and add 404 page there -- see this question [Nginx - Customizing 404 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024199/nginx-customizing-404-page)