# Hot to create Artifactory page 404 customization?

Tags: http-status-code-404, artifactory

I am using Artifactory version 6.5.2 Comunity edition.
I want to customize the 404 error page, since links to the already deleted artifacts will be available in other systems.

[Artifactory Error 404 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cngFC.png)

How to make this looks more user friendly, explaining that the artifacts you are looking for are already deleted.

Comment: Right. And where is your problem? What is your question? Please share the code you tried, point out the exact problem. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
This is not a "write my code" page, though

Comment: @planetmaker Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> explaining that the artifacts you are looking for are already deleted.

"Item <file path> does not exist" is a pretty clear explanation that the artifact isn't there, in my opinion. If you need it to distinguish between items that have never existed and items that used to exist but were deleted, that's most likely impossible.

> How to make this looks more user friendly

The 404 page that's already there is designed to be automation-friendly: it's in JSON format, which is more easily read by a script. I think the idea is that you're unlikely to open a 404 page in a browser, since the web UI wouldn't have links to 404 pages.

Artifactory doesn't have a built-in way to customize the 404 page, but you can always use a reverse-proxy (such as nginx), which can be configured to automatically intercept Artifactory's 404 responses and replace them with your custom page. Related: [Nginx - Customizing 404 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024199/nginx-customizing-404-page)