# How can i change my 404 error page in nginx configuration file?

Tags: html, nginx

i need help about my Nginx configuration file. I coded my html file. This is the config file:

```
server
    {
        listen 888;
        server_name phpmyadmin;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        root  /www/server/phpmyadmin;
            location ~ /tmp/ {
                return 403;
            }

        #error_page 404 /404-error.html;

        location ~ /*-error.html {
            try_files $1-error.html @error;
            internal;
        }

        location @error {
        root /var/www/wwwroot/umutisik.com/error_docs;
}
```

Also sorry for my bad English, not my main language.

Comment: Clarify your request. What's what you want to fix?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx - Customizing 404 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024199/nginx-customizing-404-page)